# PHP-Login - Changing code to only verify username not email

Tags: php, mysql, email, authentication, registration

UPDATE:
Sorry a lot of these comments are incorrect - the code is not susceptible to SQL Injection, I thought people would have checked it against PHP-Login.nets script. It is all escaped etc. I will link to the full script below. Also, the new SQL query I have WORKS so it cant be quotation related, the only thing that's still happening is its checking if the same PIN has been used multiple times as it thinks its the email field however I've taken out that bit of code. thats whats not making sense. Anyways heres the full page:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class registration
 * handles the user registration
 */
class Registration
{
    /**
     * @var object $db_connection The database connection
     */
    private $db_connection = null;
    /**
     * @var array $errors Collection of error messages
     */
    public $errors = array();
    /**
     * @var array $messages Collection of success / neutral messages
     */
    public $messages = array();

    /**
     * the function "__construct()" automatically starts whenever an object of this class is created,
     * you know, when you do "$registration = new Registration();"
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
            $this->registerNewUser();
        }
    }

    /**
     * handles the entire registration process. checks all error possibilities
     * and creates a new user in the database if everything is fine
     */
    private function registerNewUser()
    {
        if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Empty Username";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password_new']) || empty($_POST['user_password_repeat'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Empty Password";
        } elseif ($_POST['user_password_new'] !== $_POST['user_password_repeat']) {
            $this->errors[] = "Passwords do not match";
        } elseif (strlen($_POST['user_password_new']) < 6) {
            $this->errors[] = "Password has a minimum length of 6 characters";
        } elseif (strlen($_POST['user_name']) > 64 || strlen($_POST['user_name']) < 2) {
            $this->errors[] = "Username cannot be shorter than 2 or longer than 64 characters";
        } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $_POST['user_name'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Username does not fit the name scheme: only a-Z and numbers are allowed, 2 to 64 characters";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['user_email'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "PIN Number cannot be empty";
        } elseif (strlen($_POST['user_email']) > 4) {
            $this->errors[] = "PIN cannot be longer than 4 characters";
        } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{3,4}$/i', $_POST['user_email'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "PIN does not fit the required scheme: only a-Z and numbers are allowed, 3 to 4 characters";
        } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name'])
            && strlen($_POST['user_name']) <= 64
            && strlen($_POST['user_name']) >= 2
            && preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $_POST['user_name'])
            && !empty($_POST['user_email'])
            && strlen($_POST['user_email']) <= 4
            && !empty($_POST['user_password_new'])
            && !empty($_POST['user_password_repeat'])
            && ($_POST['user_password_new'] === $_POST['user_password_repeat'])
        ) {
            // create a database connection
            $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            // change character set to utf8 and check it
            if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
                $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
            }

            // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
            if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

                // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
                $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['user_name'], ENT_QUOTES));
                $user_email = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['user_email'], ENT_QUOTES));

                $user_password = $_POST['user_password_new'];

                // crypt the user's password with PHP 5.5's password_hash() function, results in a 60 character
                // hash string. the PASSWORD_DEFAULT constant is defined by the PHP 5.5, or if you are using
                // PHP 5.3/5.4, by the password hashing compatibility library
                $user_password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                // check if username already exists
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_email1 . "';";
                $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

                if ($query_check_user_name->num_rows == 1) {
                    $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that username is already taken.";
                } else {
                    // write new user's data into database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email)
                            VALUES('" . $user_name . "', '" . $user_password_hash . "', '" . $user_email . "');";
                    $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

                    // if user has been added successfully
                    if ($query_new_user_insert) {
                        $this->messages[] = "Your account has been created successfully. You can now log in.";
                    } else {
                        $this->errors[] = "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Sorry, no database connection.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = "An unknown error occurred.";
        }
    }
}
```

---

Ok so I'm using the php-login.net script which I must say I highly recommend having only found it a few days ago. It's highly robust, secure and easy to use!

My main issue which I cant figure out what's wrong is it is currently checking when registering a new user two things.

1) That the username hasnt been registered already.
2) That the email hasnt been registered already.

Now I'm actually using the email field as a PIN number field basically just keeping the email name to save time. So of course I dont want to be verifying if people have used the same pins as it's inevitable I only really need to know about usernames.

This is the original code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_email1 . "';";
                $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

                if ($query_check_user_name->num_rows == 1) {
                    $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that username / email address is already taken.";
                } else {
```

Now I've tried just making it

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = $user_name";
```

However there must be something else wrong with it because although it will allow me to register a user if there's nobody with the same username or pin if I register with the same PIN it shows up with "Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.". If I try the original code and use the same pin then the error shows as sorry, that username/email adress is already taken. I just don't understand I've looked all over the code and cant figure out how its still verifying the email field!!!

Any help would be VERY appreciated! All the code is exactly as it came from the website this is the only edit I'm attempting to make so re-creating the same error would be very easy!

Comment: `WHERE user_name = $user_name` that should have been quoted `WHERE user_name = '$user_name'`

Comment: You should be checking to see if the database returns errors on your queries. You are probably getting an SQL syntax error. They only show up though if you ask for them.  And this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks since you aren't using prepared statements or escaping your strings. If you deploy this as written it **will** get hacked.

Comment: Thanks, The original question has been edited as I assure you its not SQL Injection vulnerable. Also this does not fix my error. Full script is now in the question - any suggestions?

Comment: This question is not helpful to other users - it is just a request to debug your code, because you haven't made a short simple example which would almost certainly have revealed the issue to you: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your index on e-mail isn't set to unique.. .

You can just remove them in your admin panel of your mysql..

Or you could:

```
alter table users drop index email;
```

Comment: Thank you - Major facepalm on my part! Was able to drop all additional index's I'd managed to create and change the final index from unique to just an index! Now all is working correctly! Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the query like:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$user_name' //<< here
```

**But!**

As you are using mysqli_, you definately should rewrite your code to prepared statements as you are vulnerable to sql injection with your actual code. Here's a simple example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($whatever);
    $stmt->fetch();
    printf ($whatever)
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Or do yourself a favour and start using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) today.

Comment: Thank you... The original question has been edited as I assure you its not SQL Injection vulnerable. Also this does not fix my error? Full script is now in the question - any suggestions? Thanks again!